# How to remove and undo remove a gridview row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, on clicking a delete button, i need to remove the row for a while and on clicking the undo link, i need to re-display the row.

My gridview code is shown below:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="NotificationHistory" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" 
        ShowHeader="False" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast"
        FooterStyle-BorderStyle="None" EnableViewState="False" GridLines="None" >
        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast"></PagerSettings>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt="Delete" title="Delete" src="SiteImages/X.gif" 
                        onclick="changeImage(this)" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle BorderColor="#F1E8E8" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="gridItemAlignment" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgDelete" runat="server" Width="16px" Height="16px" CommandName="Remove"
                        ImageUrl="SiteImages/X.gif" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hFType" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle Height="10px" BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0" />
        <FooterStyle BorderStyle="None"></FooterStyle>
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="#999999"></PagerStyle>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblHistory" runat="server">No History.</asp:Label>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

My html :

```
<table id="ctl00_Content_NotificationHistory" class="home-history-grid" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-color: rgb(241, 232, 232); border-style: none; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr class="home-history-grid-row">
<td>
<img height="16px" width="16px" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="SiteImages/X.gif" title="Delete" alt="Delete">
</td>
<td class="gridItemStyle" style="border: 1px solid rgb(241, 232, 232); width: 75%;">
<a href="ReportCreation.aspx?rid=207">Status Report for Kalista as on 05/03/2012</a>
</td>
<td class="gridItemAlignment" style="border: 1px solid rgb(241, 232, 232);">Saved</td>
<td>
<img id="ImgDelete" height="16px" width="16px" onclick="deleteRow(this)" src="SiteImages/X.gif" alt="">
<input id="ctl00_Content_NotificationHistory_ctl02_hFType" type="hidden" value="Cirrus.CirrusObjects.Report" name="ctl00$Content$NotificationHistory$ctl02$hFType">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="home-history-grid-row">
<td>
</td>
<td class="gridItemStyle" style="border: 1px solid rgb(241, 232, 232); width: 75%;">
</td>
<td class="gridItemAlignment" style="border: 1px solid rgb(241, 232, 232);">Saved</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My javascript to remove the row (This is removing the selected row, now i would like to know how i can re-display it on the same place):

```
 function deleteRow(imageElement) {
            var img = $(imageElement);
            imageElement.setAttribute("id", "selectedRow");
            alert($("selectedRow").siblings(":image"));
            var row = $(imageElement).closest('tr');
            $(row).remove();
        }
```

Comment: I need guidance on how i can do that. I don't know how to fetch the row and hide it. Need a guidance. That would be helpful.

Comment: Gridview will e converted to html table and i dont know how i can name the rows. Is there any way to get the index of the corresponding table row using javascript ?

Comment: Can u paste the html that this GridView generates?

Comment: @nz_karl , please find the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this $(row).remove() to

`$(row).hide();` it will be hidden, when you want to show it again do  `$(row).show();`

or even this will be more slicker

`$(row).toggle();` ( behind the scene it will be setting display='none' to hide)

Comment: The toggle actually needs to happen on clicking an 'undo' link outside the grid, how can i get the row out there? i used a hidden field and set the value of the row to it. i can see the value as [object object]. But on alerting $("hiddenRow").val() , it's undefined.

Comment: $("#hiddenRow").val() try like this

Comment: Thanks Ravi, that was one issue and my hidden field value wasnt helping too. So i set the id of the selected row as a flag and it worked. You answer helped me to do that. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

This will show/hide the row

```
$(row).toggle();
```

Comment: Can you check the comment above please?